# How to open Apple's default app from the other app on Apple Watch?

Tags: watchkit, swift5, ios14, xcode12

I have developed watchOS app that is only for Apple Watch not integration with iPhone app. From that need to open Apple's default app. such as :

- Map
- Setting
- Health
- HeartRate
- Sleep
- Workout

On iPhone we are open any app via `URLScheme` or `open(url:)`, but how can we achieve same functionality on watchOS?

on iPhone :

```
let url = "abc.com"
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL, options: nil) { (finished) in
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent on `WatchKit`. You can use [openSystemURL(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/1628224-opensystemurl) to make a call or send a message, but You can't open another app.